# No token generate and appending to the jwt token once logged in redirect

Tags: functions

If no token is there redirecting to pdf file and generate token appending and logged in redirecting the user to pdf

Comment: can you edit your question to add more information? There's no code and you mentioned JWT tokens but JWT tokens aren't a feature of WordPress. Are you asking for help with a plugin?